# I need help understanding the best implementation of function modifiers

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SomeContract{

   address public owner;

    modifier ownerOnly{
        if(msg.sender == owner) _;  //would this use less gas than the modifier below?
    }

    modifier ownerOnly{
        if(msg.sender != owner) revert();  //is this modifier more secure?
        _;
    }

   function SomeContract(){
      owner = msg.sender;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple contract and tested it in [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;

contract TestContract {

    address owner;

    modifier ownerOnly1 {
        if(msg.sender == owner) _;  //would this use less gas than the modifier below?
    }

    modifier ownerOnly2 {
        if(msg.sender != owner) revert();  //is this modifier more secure?
        _;
    }

    function TestContract() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function foo()
    ownerOnly1    // or ownerOnly2
    returns (uint answer)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Here are the costs for calling `foo()` as `owner`:

For `ownerOnly1`: transaction cost 21570, execution cost 298.

For `ownerOnly2`: transaction cost 21573, execution cost 301.

However, when calling `foo()` from another account, `ownerOnly2` causes an exception, but `ownerOnly1` does not (returns `0` instead of `42`). I suppose the `ownerOnly2` effect is desirable.

Note that you can write this condition in a more readable way: `require(msg.sender == owner)` (see [documentation on error handling](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)).

Comment: @ZenosPavlakou you're welcome! You can accept it if it solved your problem :)